# Telegram on iOS application

Tags: ios, iphone, telegram

Is there a way to integrate **telegram** on my iOS application? 
If so how and with which flow? Can someone help me with tutorial or another info? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use their API http://core.telegram.org

They have open sourced their official iOS App too. You can easily follow the code and build your own. https://telegram.org/apps#telegram-for-iphone